# Queue.Contains returns false instead of true

Tags: c#, collections

developers! 
I finally lost the logic. What is the issue of this code? 
It has to return true for me, cuz Queue include name Jack. 
Why not? Do I use a method in incorrect way?
Thank you for your answering on my simple question!

```
 namespace DataStructures
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Queue<Employee> line = new Queue<Employee>();
                line.Enqueue(new Employee { Name = "Jack" });
                line.Enqueue(new Employee { Name = "Nick" });
                line.Enqueue(new Employee { Name = "Vova" });
                line.Enqueue(new Employee { Name = "Andrew" });

                Console.WriteLine(line.Contains(new Employee { Name = "Jack" }));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        class Employee
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is running fine and it is absolutely normal that it prints "false".

The type that you called Employee is a class and so it is a reference type. 
By default, reference types are compared **by reference**. 
This is the equality semantics defined in System.Object and it is inherited by all classes unless an override of the Equals method is provided.

Each time you write the code new Employee() you are creating a **new instance of the class employee**: this basically means that you are creating a **new object** and that you are allocating **new memory in the heap** (which is the part of the computer memory where C# objects live).

Look at the following code:

```
var mark = new Employee(){ Name = "Mark" };
var henry = new Employee() { Name = "Henry" };

var areEquals = mark.Equals(henry);
var areSameReference = Object.ReferenceEquals(mark, henry);

Console.WriteLine(areEquals); // this will print false
Console.Writeline(areSameReference); // this will print false
```

In the above code you are creating two different instances of the class Employee and doing so you are creating two different objects in the heap (in other words you are allocating two different memory spaces in order to store two different objects). That's why when you call Equals you get false, because by default reference types are compared by reference.

When you call Object.ReferenceEquals on the variables mark and henry you get false, because that variables are reference to two different memory address, because the two objects that you created are stored in distinct memory address of the heap.

If you want to compare your Employee objects with a different semantics, for instance by comparing their names, you must override both Equals and GetHashCode. I suggest you to read carefully an introductory book on C# such as [this one](https://www.apress.com/la/book/9781484213339)